# Error access denied in microsoft graph api to read user messages

Tags: ms-office, postman, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

When I call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages` in Postman, it returns this error:

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "ea5ef6c7-5c89-4ad6-975f-aec77e6f5064",
        "date": "2019-02-25T12:00:07"
        }
    }
}
```

Provide all permission that the app needs. Except this "Use Exchange Web Services with full access to all mailboxes" in office 365 Exchange online and also give grant permission but still can't access.

[image: center image description here]
[image: Permission images]

Comment: How are you obtaining the token?

Comment: By using this things in postman

    client_id:{{client_id}}
    client_secret:{{client_secret}}
    resource:https://graph.microsoft.com
    grant_type:client_credentials

Comment: How did you register your application and have you received Admin Consent?

Comment: Yes i have business account and i gave the permission as Admin and also grant permission.

Comment: Where did you register the app?

Comment: In Azure cloud - > Active Directory

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you set the permissions for your app in the Azure Portal here:

[image]

Comment: @ShubhamGupta You have a token with the claims Mail.Read.  I cannot tell what authorization server provided that claim.  You mention Exchange Web Services and Exchange Online which are unrelated to Microsoft Graph.  Can you try making this same call in Graph Explorer to see if it works for you? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: yes i https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer/ it works here..
using this same token i can see my mail folders.
Earlier it worked fine but now it is causing some problem with same scopes.
i think microsoft change some scopes. that cause problem.